# How to bind class that inherit from collection wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, binding

i'm pretty new in wpf and i'm having troubles with a simple `ListBox` binding.

This is the case, i have two clases

```
public class Child, ImplementedPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ChildCollection : IObservableCollection<Child>
{
    new public void Add(Child child)
    {
        //some logic
        base.Add(child);
    }
}
```

And i'm trying to bind it in xaml

```
<Window x:Class="GeneradorDeCarpetaPlanos.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GeneradorDeCarpetaPlanos"
        xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:GeneradorDeCarpetaPlanos.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Window.DataContext>
            <VM:ChildCollection></VM:ChildCollection>
        </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>       

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And in the code behind

```
ChildCollection childs = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        childs = new ChildCollection();            
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = childs;
    }
```

I try to bind the `Count` property to a simple `TextBlock` and that is showing the `Count` but not updating with `ChildCollection` object

How shoud i bind it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you explicitly add a `ListBoxItem` to the ListBox.

You probably wanted to define the `ItemTemplate` instead:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You should also consider using an ObservableCollection instead of creating your own collection class:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Child> children = new ObservableCollection<Child>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in iappropriate definition of the cobservable collection. Anyway for the learning scenario try to  use the standard predefined System.ObservableCollection<> instead. The collection also have to be initialized (not nbe null) in that little experiment...

So in your case, please try as the follows:

```
ObservablledCollection<Child> childs = new ObservableCollection<Child>;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = childs;
}
```

Comment: I try but it throw `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` i think this is wrong `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">` but i'm not sure